# How to perform stacking of tensors in a loop when there are many stacking elements?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to stack tensors. I use tf.stack() for that purpose. However, the elements I need to stack changes. However, I will know their count. So, is there a way to perform the stacking in a loop?

I have I as a tensor of shape : [batch_size,256,256,1]
and I have i as a tensor of shape [256,256,1].

```
# I used to do
I = tf.stack([i, i, i, i, i]) # if batch_size is 5
# But I can have a varying value of batch_size.
```

Comment: How those tensors are stored? If they are in a list, then you can easily pass that list to `tf.stack`. If they are all already in a tensor as a batch, then what/why do you want to stack?

Comment: I have individual tensors of same shape. They are not stored in a list.

Comment: Can you give an example of the tensors are so that you can't easily use `tf.stack`?